# Why two logically same conditions in postgresql case clause have different behavior?

Tags: sql, postgresql, lazy-evaluation, order-of-execution

I have two queries is postgresql:

```
1. SELECT CASE WHEN (1=1) THEN NULL ELSE cast(1/0 as text) END;
2. SELECT CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT 10)) THEN NULL ELSE cast(1/0 as text) END;
```

As you might have noticed result of the first condition in both queries is true, but result of first query is `null` and result of the second one is `ERROR: division by zero`

What is happening in here?

Is there any optimization in order of evaluation occurring? If yes, is there any why to turn it off?

Is there any why to have a complex query in the condition block that doesn't trigger runtime error in else block when result of condition is true?

Postgresql version: 13.1

Comment: `3. SELECT CASE WHEN (SELECT 1=1) THEN NULL ELSE cast(1/0 as text) END;` to check whether it is a subquery that fails to be short-circuited.

Comment: See here [CASE](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/functions-conditional.html#FUNCTIONS-CASE): "As described in Section 4.2.14, there are various situations in which subexpressions of an expression are evaluated at different times, so that the principle that “CASE evaluates only necessary subexpressions” is not ironclad. For example a constant 1/0 subexpression will usually result in a division-by-zero failure at planning time, even if it's within a CASE arm that would never be entered at run time". Section [4.2.14](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/12/sql-expressions.html#SYNTAX-EXPRESS-EVAL)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The error happens when the query is being planned, not when it is run.

In the first case, 1=1 is known to be true at planning time, causing the entire CASE to collapse to just NULL::text.  So the constant folding of `1=1` and of `CASE WHEN true` saves you from the constant-folding exception of `1/0`.  You can see this by doing EXPLAIN VERBOSE.

> Is there any why to have a complex query in the condition block that doesn't trigger runtime error in else block when result of condition is true?

Yes, except it isn't really at run time where the problem manifests.

Just like a dummy SELECT defeats the constant folding that prevents the problem, another dummy select can defeat the constant folding that causes the problem.

```
SELECT CASE WHEN (EXISTS (SELECT 10)) THEN NULL::text ELSE cast (1/(select 0) as text)  END;
```